# C#:How can I compare between the sum of every row in 2D array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I would like to know how can I check if the sum of every row in 2D array is equal to each other.

Edit: I tired the way Mike suggested but i still got the index out of range. What am I missing?

```
 bool sumSame;
          int sum3=0;
          int sum4 = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
          {
              sum3 += arr[0, i];
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
          {
              sum4 = 0;
              for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); i++)
              {
                  **sum4 += arr[i, j];**//The Error is Here
              }
              if (sum4 != sum3)
              {
                  sumSame = false;
                  break;
              }
          }
          sumSame = true
```

Comment: Can you how us example of an input array?

Comment: If you want to access `arr[i + 1, ...]`, you need to constrain `i` to `[0, arr.GetLength(0) - 1)`. Adapt your `for` loop for that. However, even with this update, the procedure is quite inefficient because it calculates all row sums twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would like to know if all rows in a 2D array have the same sum.

So, you need to write a function which computes the sum of a row.

Then your problem becomes one-dimensional: check whether a function invoked for every element of a one-dimensional array returns the same value for each element.  (The fact that an element is in turn another array is irrelevant.)

If you do not want to (or do not know how to) write a function, then you can write the code which computes the sum of a row as a nested loop, (as you already tried to do,) but still, it helps if you conceptually treat these two tasks as completely different from each other, meaning that they should not mix their variables, and the outer loop should only use the result of the calculation of the inner loop.

Generally, the way we make sure that all elements of an array are equal to a certain value is that we compute the value of the first element, (at index 0,) and then we loop for each *subsequent* element (`for( int i = 1; ...`) and check whether the value computed for this element is equal to the value that we got for the first element.

Comment: Can you take a look at the code I edited , I still get the error.

Comment: When you get an error, you need to be telling us precisely on which line you get it.  I suspect it is at the first `sum3 += arr[0, i];` and it is because the first `arr.GetLength(0);` should be `arr.GetLength(1);` instead.

Comment: Ok, the error is in the third loop: `sum4 += arr[i, j];` . And both dimnasions are equal (it's a square(4X4)) .

Comment: It is because your loop works with `j`, but you are incrementing `i`.

Comment: Advice: learn to use the visual studio debugger.  It will save you from a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the sum of each array to the `List<int>` and check the number of distinct results with `Distinct().Count()`, if it's 1 the results are the same for all 2D array.

```
int[,] arr = new int[,]
{
    {1,2,3 },
    {3,2,1 },
    {2,3,1 }
};

List<int> sums = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
{
     int sum = 0;
     for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
     {
         sum += arr[i, j];      
     }
     sums.Add(sum);
}

bool sameResults = sums.Distinct().Count() == 1;
```

Comment: This is not a '2d' array.